# connect MS sql 2005 in PHP using ms_connect

Tags: php, sql-server

I have the problem with PHP connect and work with MS SQL. I found on the internet the function named mssql_connect() can connect it and just active the function by remove ; before it in php.ini. However, after i restart my appserv 2.5.10 , I can't see mssql_connect in phpinfo.php page. Anyone can give me a suggestion. Thanks in advance!

my php.ini file

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_dbase.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fdf.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_ifx.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_mcrypt.dll
;extension=php_mhash.dll
;extension=php_mime_magic.dll
extension=php_ming.dll
extension=php_msql.dll
extension=php_mssql.dll
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
;extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_zip.dll
```

Note: I don't use IIS ( does it affect? )

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check php_msql.dll is available in folder, If not you need to download from internet...

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, yes. It has in ext folder already.